# How to use Stitch to stitch images

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-stitching

I used OpenCV's subtitler to stitch together images, but the effect was not what I wanted
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXl0a.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGPYB.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAqwE.jpg
This question requires a friend who can understand Chinese to answer

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# 读取两张图像
image1 = cv2.imread('.\\key\\key11.png')
image2 = cv2.imread('.\\key\\key12.png')

# 获取图像高度和宽度
height1, width1 = image1.shape[:2]
height2, width2 = image2.shape[:2]

# 获取最宽宽度
max_width = max(width1, width2)

# 计算放大倍率
scaling_factor1 = max_width / width1
scaling_factor2 = max_width / width2

# 调整图像大小并进行比例放大
image1_resized = cv2.resize(image1, (max_width, int(height1 * scaling_factor1)))
image2_resized = cv2.resize(image2, (max_width, int(height2 * scaling_factor2)))

# 创建一条分界线
isLine = False
line_color = (0, 0, 255)  # 线的颜色（BGR）
line_thickness = 2  # 线的厚度
line = np.ones((5, max_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8) * line_color

# 垂直拼接图像和分界线
if isLine:
    combined_image = np.vstack((image1_resized, line, image2_resized))
else:
    combined_image = np.vstack((image1_resized, image2_resized))

# 保存拼接后的图像
cv2.imwrite("combined_image.png", combined_image)
print("图像拼接完成。")
```

Comment: Well, you used numpy's vertical stack, so the images got stacked vertically... you might be looking for [horizontal stacking](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy.hstack).

Comment: I think this is what you want : https://blog.csdn.net/holly_Z_P_F/article/details/125096360